# Constraint check

Tags: sql, constraints

we are trying to create a constraint that decides whether a grade should be F or not. If a course isn't finished then the student should get the grade F. Else the student should get another grade.

This is our constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Registrerad_på ADD CONSTRAINT chk_avslutadkurs CHECK (CASE WHEN FinishedCourse 
= 'No' THEN Grade = 'F')
```

Grade is a varchar(50) column that accepts null values and FinishedCourse is the same, except it cant contain null values and it only contains 'Yes' values at this time. The table Registrerad_på contains data (int and varchar(50)).

The question: What is wrong with the Check, the error arises at the last "=" at the THEN statement. Please tell me if i need to add some more information, sorry if it is unclear.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Second hint. Ask an actual question.

Comment: First of all, does the table already have data? Secondly, what's the type on the chk_avslutadkurs column? Does the column already have 0's & 1's or Yes or No? All that will need to be determined before you can create the constraint.... In the future, include that type of information.

Comment: I agree with you comments, `chk_avslutadkurs` is not a column though, it's a constraint name.

Comment: Sorry about that, i reconstructed the question. I hope it is better now, please tell me if I need to supply more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraint is

```
ALTER TABLE Registrerad_på 
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_avslutadkurs 
CHECK (CASE WHEN FinishedCourse = 'No' THEN Grade = 'F')
```

The skeleton syntax for a CASE statement (standard SQL) is usually

```
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END
```

So you need at least the END keyword.

```
CHECK (CASE WHEN FinishedCourse = 'No' THEN Grade = 'F' END)
```

But you *probably* really need something more like this.

```
CHECK (CASE WHEN FinishedCourse = 'No' THEN Grade = 'F' 
            WHEN FinishedCourse = 'Yes' THEN Grade IN ('A','B','C','D','F')
            ELSE Grade = 'Somebody let some bad data into FinishedCourse'
       END)
```

Think about adding another constraint on FinishedCourse.

```
CHECK (FinishedCourse IN ('Yes', 'No') )
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I'm sure this will help.